# views_post_execute white screen by $view output

Tags: drupal, view

I got a white screen when i try to write the $view variable to the output per var_dump, per devel module and so on. If i run a test with dvm('test'); everything works as expected.

```
function feeds_node_processor_global_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  dvm($view->name);
  if($view->name == 'liveticker_start2'){
    //dvm($view->total_rows);
    //dvm("test");
    //var_dump($view);
  }
  if ($view->total_rows > 100) {
   drupal_set_message(t('You have more than 100 hits.'));
  }
}
```

In watchdog aren't any errors and i don't have access to the apache log (at the moment).
Are there any other clues?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://drupal.org/node/158043 about the White Screen of Death.

I've run into a similar issue in the past and it's because I've ran out of php memory trying to output the `$view` object, I think.  Your server's logs may help verify this if you could access it but since you can't, try increasing your PHP's `memory_limit` if you can.